# Insertion into HashMap changes values in other stored HashMaps

Tags: java

Ok, I'm stumped by this one I have no idea what's causing this problem.  The problem I am having occurs in a class that when given a text file, will find the number of instances of one letter coming after another.  So I have a HashMapCharacter, HashMap that stores all of this.  The keys of the hash are all the characters contained in the text, and each of these characters corresponds to an inner Hash containing the number of cases of a character(inner hash key) after the outerhash key.  The inner hash with key 'a' would contain the number of times 'b' comes after 'a', the number of times 'c' comes after 'a', the number of times 'z' comes after 'a', so on and so forth for all the characters that come after 'a'.  MuteableInt just holds an int value, and allows it to be incremented by method.

The error occurs when I compute the total of all the counts contained in each inner Hash.  I find the total, and then I insert it under the key '~'.  The total is correct when I insert it, but when I pull out the total later, I find that for every inner Hash the total takes on the value of the last total I entered.

```
currHash.put('~', total);
```

So, when analyzing War and Peace the last total entered is that of 'x', which has a total count of 3987. When I pull out the total instance count of 'h', or any other character, it is also 3987.  Hopefully this makes sense, here is the offending code.

```
public class CountTransitions {

HashMap<Character, HashMap<Character, MuteableInt>> counts;

public void calcTotal() {
Iterator<Character> iterator = counts.keySet().iterator();
        HashMap<Character, MuteableInt> currHash;
        char curr, next;
        MuteableInt total = new MuteableInt(0);
        MuteableInt count = new MuteableInt(0);

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            curr = iterator.next();
            currHash = counts.get(curr);
            total.set(0);
            Iterator<Character> innerIt = currHash.keySet().iterator();
            while (innerIt.hasNext()) {
                next = innerIt.next();
                count = currHash.get(next);
                total.add(count);
            }//end while
            System.out.println("Total: " + total);
            currHash.put('~', total);
        }//end while
}
}//end class
```

Comment: Most people seem to have the right answer. Because Java stores objects by reference and you never change the reference to total by creating a new object so it is continuously reset. If you are looking for the quick fix; replace the line `total.set(0);` with `total = new MuteableInt(0);`

Comment: Yeah I switched to using an Integer, and make a new Integer every iteration for total, and works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only ever create one `MuteableInt` for `total`, and put this same object reference into each sub-`HashMap`. This is why they're changing -- it's one counter you're incrementing everywhere, not many.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the *same* `MutableInt` object every time. You need to create a new object for each character you add to the `HashMap`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that at all!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the **same** `MuteableInt` as the value of all of the hash. Why don't you just use a primitive wrapper `Integer`, this way whenever you make changes a new integer is created and you wont modify the old one.

Considers simpler problem where you set the hash a, b, c,  d to 1, 2, 3 ,4 respectively:

Using a `MuteableInt` and modifying its value before each insert

> key(a) -> int value 1
>
> key(b) -> change original int to 2 and link to it
>
> key(c) -> change original int to 3 and link to it
>
> key(d) -> change original int to 4 and link to it
>
> **All keys will be 4**

Where if you are using `Integer` which is `Immutable`

> set(a) -> create an int with value 1
>
> key(b) -> create **another** int with value 2
>
> key(c) -> create **a third** int with value 3
>
> key(d) -> create **yet another** int with value 4
>
> **Correct behavior.**

...

Comment: My reason for using a class which I could increment was so when I wanted to add to a value to the inner hash I could do counts.get(curr).increment() instead of having to first get the value out, create a new integer with an incremented value, and put it back in.  Is the overhead of having a get and a put instead of just a get substantial enough to worry about?

Comment: This overhead of the read is nothing. If you consider how MutableInteger work, it still have to read the value and write it back in its implementation of "increment()", so you are not saving any time. If anything, this would (likely) be slower than such a light weight primitive wrapper as Integer. MutableInteger is used when you want to save space and when you WANT all reference to point to the same value.